# Copying the data from a power query without duplicating it

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm automatically making lists in different sheets from power queries by use of macros (I import the Power Query to a separate sheet and filter the query for the value I want, then I copy all entrances of the query that show up).
It can happen that the query only has one list that I want to make from it. If this happens I copy the complete query, which also duplicates it into the "Queries & Connections" list.

When looking it up, I could only find tutorials on how to load a power query to excel. I would just like to copy the values (which happens when I only copy filtered power queries, but not when there are no values to be filtered out).
Is there a way of just copying the values without duplicating the query?

Comment: Have you tried copying, then pasting values? Why the VBA tag?

Comment: Ow sorry, I edited the question. I use VBA to automatically generate these lists and sheets.

Comment: If you load a PowerQuery result into a PivotTable report, then you can easily use the same data again without a new duplicate query by duplicating the first PivotTable report and then adjusting it as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches that I would consider.

"Refer to" the original query to generate "sub-queries" in Power Query to apply the filters for you, is probably the best approach.

You will possibly end up with some empty sheets - use your VBA to hide or delete them if they don't contain any data.

The way you describe the problem implies that you are using .Copy / .Paste within VBA - that is bad practice. Consider instead using `ToRange.Value = FromRange.Value`

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed using the .copy/.paste commands. This is giving some other problems though, but I think I can get it to work from here!